# Why does Wolfram introduce an unknown parameter in the solution to this initial value problem?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to get the solution of the problem inputted below. However, the solution to the differential equation given by Wolfram makes use of a parameter that was not part of the problem and seems to offer no explanation of what it would be.

What would  Csi be here? Where could I read more on that?

[image: Wolfram Error]

[Link to the problem above on Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28ap%2Bb%29p%27%28x%29%20%3D%20%28cp%2Bd%29%2F%28K*A%29*m%20%2B%20%280.55%2F%28sqrt%28K%29*A%5E2%29%29*m%5E2%2C%20p%280%29%3Df)

Comment: I am GUESSING your "Csi" is the Greek letter `Xi` and I'm GUESSING that is coming from its interpretation of your `K`  Try substituting an "ordinary" variable name, like `b` and see if that replaces the `Xi` with `b` or perhaps helps it solve your problem a little further. If I use the full Mathematica instead of WolframAlpha then it can only find a solution in terms of the inverse function of a big complicated expression when given a big complicated argument. so that is probably why it gives you a large expression in terms of `p(x)` instead of `p(x)=expression not involving p(x)`

Comment: IF you can carefully justify getting rid of those denominators and replacing your sqrt(k) by k and thus your other k by k^2. That may mean that Wolfram doesn't have to wonder about if and where your denominators might be zero and about square roots of negative numbers. Doing that might mean that Wolfram could actually find a solution for you. If you were doing all this by hand you would probably just ignore those possibilities.